# Compare a string against a list of newly created booleans without looping,

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have created a list of new booleans in javascript, belonging to boolean values in different languages (true, false, verdadero, falso, ratt, fel, etc...)

I have done so with:

```
var false_swedish = new Boolean("fel");
```

and so on with many others.

I am trying to code a small text game as a kind of puzzle to learn (I am very beginner), so I am stuck here. Now my goal is: Since I have a list of 10 new booleans, how can I compare them against a string (what the user writes using a `prompt`)?

I was thinking first about creating an array with all the new words and then compare them with the string, but that defeats the point of declaring them as new Booleans and finding out if the user input is boolean, and here I am not very interested in the final result but more in the process of doing it (as I said, is just an exercise to learn)

I got as far as creating a function that checks if a variable is a Boolean, basically using:

```
if (value.constructor == Boolean ){
    return true;
```

and then using that function to add a new `method` to String with `prototype`, so I can check against the string provided by `prompt`. But of course, that function is useless, because it's assuming that the variables might be booleans, and they are not. They are always strings...

Am I trying to complicate it too much?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Why not just use a hash/map/associative array/whatever you want to call it?

Comment: It does not work. `new Boolean("false")` just generates a `Boolean` object wrapper for *`true`*, as the non-empty string is a truthy value

Comment: I am not worried about which value the new `Boolean` receives. I just need to know if it's a `Boolean` value or other kind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are trying to complicate it too much.

`new Boolean("any string")` is useless, since with any non-empty string the resulting variable would be true. If your goal was to check whether the user entered `'true` or `'false'` only, the best solution would be to compare his input to `'true'`. But in case there are lots of possible inputs, you can use an object:

```
// this object contains every string value you want to include in your script defined by a number
var predefinedValues = {'true': 1, 'false': 0, 'verdadero':1, 'falso':0};
// i assume userInput contains user input
if(predefinedValues[userInput] == 1) {
    //true
}
else {
    //false or not found in array
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally decided to use your approach, since I was getting very confused with the definition of new Booleans, so I suspect that I was going by the wrong path. Yours is the most logical solution.